# PL/SQL how to call this function

Tags: oracle, plsql

I created record, cursor and this function and I don't know how to call it. Can you please help me with that?

```
DECLARE
TYPE EmpRecTyp IS RECORD (
 emp_id       NUMBER(6),
 salary       NUMBER(8,2));
CURSOR desc_salary RETURN EmpRecTyp IS
  SELECT employee_id, salary FROM employees ORDER BY salary DESC;
emp_rec     EmpRecTyp;
FUNCTION nth_highest_salary (n INTEGER) RETURN EmpRecTyp IS
BEGIN
  OPEN desc_salary;
  FOR i IN 1..n LOOP
     FETCH desc_salary INTO emp_rec;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE desc_salary;
  RETURN emp_rec;
END nth_highest_salary;
BEGIN
  NULL;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you test this:

```
Begin
     emp_rec := nth_highest_salary(1);
End;
```

The thing is if you want to use this function globally you have to define that type globally too.

Also depending on your oracle version you need to initialize the record variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
FUNCTION nth_highest_salary (n INTEGER) RETURN EmpRecTyp IS
TYPE EmpRecTyp IS RECORD (
 emp_id       NUMBER(6),
 salary       NUMBER(8,2));
CURSOR desc_salary RETURN EmpRecTyp IS
  SELECT employee_id, salary FROM employees ORDER BY salary DESC;
emp_rec     EmpRecTyp;
BEGIN
  OPEN desc_salary;
  FOR i IN 1..n LOOP
     FETCH desc_salary INTO emp_rec;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE desc_salary;
  RETURN emp_rec;
END nth_highest_salary;
/
```

then

SELECT nth_highest_salary (n) FROM DUAL;

Answer (score 0):

Just declare a variable of EmpRecTyp and you'll be able to call your function like this:

```
DECLARE 
  vl_emprectyp EmpRecTyp;
BEGIN
  vl_emprectyp := nth_highest_salary(1);
END;
```

Notice that this code will work only on the scope of your block pl/sql.

Answer (score 0):

Because you've made the function local to a block you can only call it from within that block. I suggest that in your code above you replace

```
BEGIN
  NULL;
END;
```

with

```
BEGIN
  emp_rec := nth_highest_salary(1);
END;
```

Best of luck.